# Selenium C# weaknesses

Tags: node.js, selenium

We are embarking on integrating Selenium into our web projects (something we’ve been meaning to do for quite some time).

I’ve read a few articles that argue whether to use C#, node, python etc with selenium, but even those articles tend to finish by saying go with which ever language you already know best. That would put us firmly in the C# camp. I’d be quite happy with this approach because it gives me all the things I’m used to - VS, Intelkisense, Debugger etc, however one niggle in my mind tells me that using a flavour of JavaScript is going to provide better access to the elements in the DOM compared to C# - I might want tests to check the padding on an element, the height of an element, or the x/y position of an element. In standard web programming you would never dream of trying to evaluate these checks in c# - you’d always opt for JavaScript, so my question becomes whether using JavaScript to script selenium tests actually provides stronger functionality than in C#? Can anyone advise?

Many thanks
dotdev

Comment: Selenium has pretty much the same capabilities across all of its implementations. Go with the given advice -- use the language you are most comfortable testing with. Using JS to drive selenium does not give you distinct advantages over, say, C# or Java. Personally, I love the Python API for selenium, but that's because Python is my language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the Selenium WebDriver has the ability to execute javascript in the middle of a test run

```
IWebDriver myDriver = new WebDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) myDriver;  
js.executeScript(yourJavascriptHere);
```

More importantly, I would definitely recommend using the programming language you and your team are most familiar with.

Here are a few of my reasons why:

- As you mentioned, **you get to use tools you are familiar with**. Working within the same IDE is a huge plus when you are correcting bugs that were found in a UI Test run.
- You can also **Reuse Utility Libraries** you may have already written for your web applications. You will may still need to use Logging, Data Access and other infrastructure
- Easier Deployments. The ability to run all tests on build
- **Inheritance with strongly typed objects comes in handy** when creating an UI Testing Framework. Essentially all of the HTML paths, css, etc. can be abstracted out.

John Sonmez has a great course on Pluralsight about creating an automated testing framework with C#. I recommend you check it out if Pluralsight is a resource you have available to you.

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/automated-testing-framework-selenium/table-of-contents

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You saw it right *go with which ever language you already know best* is the best policy.

The current version of *Selenium* are released through five major *Language Bindings Art* (several minor) as follows :

- **Java**
- **C#**
- **Ruby**
- **Python**
- **Javascript (Node)**

It is worth to be mentioned that the *Selenium* team takes utmost care while releasing the *Selenium* libraries through different *Language Bindings Arts*. All the *Selenium Clients* are released at par with the new/updated/enhanced/bug-fixed functionalities. Hence irrespective of the *Selenium Language Bindings Art* you use, your experiance will be indifferent.

But the efficiency of designing/coding/implementing a framework to work will *Selenium* can make a lot of difference in terms of effectiveness and performance. Hence selecting the selection of *Selenium Language Bindings Art* effectively boils down to **go with which ever language you already know best**.

### [A bit of Selenium History](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp#brief-history-of-the-selenium-project)

Selenium in early stage was developed as a **Javascript library** that could drive interactions with a webpage which allowed him to automatically rerun tests against multiple browsers. That library eventually became **Selenium Core**.

Though at that time *Selenium* was a tremendous tool but it had it's own drawbacks. As a result of **Javascript based Automation Engine** and the security restrictions browsers apply to *Javascript* a lot of things were impossible to achieve.

It was in 2006 an engineer from Google developed a testing tool that spoke directly to the browser using the **native method** for the browser and operating system to avoid the restrictions of a sandboxed Javascript environment which is the **WebDriver** we know as of today.

Hence the conclusion can be using **NodeJS** it's **Advantage You !!!**

Comment: this conclusion makes no sense